# Man pages conflict on thread-safe

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

There's a conflict between man pages which I don't understand.

[man 7 pthreads](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) says that:

> POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008 require that all functions
> specified in the standard shall be thread-safe, except for the
> following functions:

and exit() isn't in the thread-safety exception list.

However, [man 3 exit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) says:

> The exit() function uses a global variable that is not protected, so it is not thread-safe.

By googling it seems that `exit()` is actually thread unsafe. So what's wrong with my understanding of man pages? Why is `exit()` not listed as thread unsafe in `man 7 pthreads`?

Comment: The specification of `exit()` in [POSIX-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) doesn't say that `exit()` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Barmar But the man page cited is claiming the non-thread safe `exit` is conforming POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008, which are requiting it to be thread safe

Comment: It just seems wrong.

Comment: There is no conflict. One describes POSIX, the other describes GNU/Linux. While GNU/Linux tries to be mostly POSIX compatible where it's possible and makes sense, it's not POSIX certified and there is no formal POSIX guarantee.

Comment: If I had to guess? It's not thread safe for the same reason `TerminateProcess` on windows isn't thread safe... it's basically taking a wrecking ball to the process. Calling any method anywhere in the process after calling `exit` not already registered with `atexit` is effectively undefined behavior. `atexit` is basically your one chance to save the pictures before the house gets torn down.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: @thatotherguy Why does the man page say it conforms to POSIX if it has this incompatibility?

Comment: The definition of safe in that document: A thread-safe function is one that can be safely (i.e., it will deliver the same results regardless of whether it is) called from multiple threads at the same time. By that definition, perhaps exit is indeed safe to call from any thread ! But the Man 3 maybe using a different definition of safe. I wonder.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop Maybe, but https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html says that the text is mostly taken from POSIX.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop calling `exit` more than once is [guaranteed undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) by the C standard from whence it comes. Ditto calling `quick_exit` after calling `exit`

Comment: Great find, Mgetz ! All the more reason to call pthread_exit only and not exit, if using pthreads.

Comment: @Mgetz "Guaranteed undefined behavior" sounds like oxymoron :)

Comment: @kalyanswaroop it's valid to tear down the process without cleaning up, you may not even have control of all threads as they may have been created by other libraries. It's on them to register `atexit` and `at_quick_exit` handlers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I mean it's undefined from a C or C++ language perspective. From the world of kernel colored glasses the behavior is extremely well defined: The process will exit and the resources reclaimed by the kernel.

Comment: AFAICT the wording you quoted from the exit manpage comes from the glibc manual, and describes that implementation, see:  https://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/manual/startup.texi#l822

Comment: Obsessing about an apparent contradiction between two otherwise unrelated "man" pages is silly: a complete waste of time and energy.  Your *REAL* takeway is in  
[Mgetz's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69367858/3135317): `exit is not thread safe`.  Moreover: `if you're tearing down the house does it really matter if the house was constructed to code anymore? Worrying about closing the drapes when the bulldozer is coming through the wall is kind of pointless.`

Comment: In general I wouldn't worry about what POSIX says at all. It contains numerous other contractions too, and often conflicts with standard C. One of the biggest mistakes made during C standardization was to include a random bunch of very old, bad API Unix crap functions in the standard. Instead of making a completely new library. POSIX didn't fix this mess, but rather encouraged the use of messy old crap further. The only good parts of POSIX are therefore those parts where they actually designed something new and useful, such as the pthreads library... and that's about all good it did.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is `exit()` not listed as thread unsafe in `man 7 pthreads`?

That is a question for the documentation authors. But I can say why it should never be considered thread safe (from a userspace/c language perspective). It is explicitly listed as: well it's complicated.

You can't legally call `exit` twice, so that takes care of the data race. Because even if you did it's already explictly undefined behavior to call `exit` or `quick_exit` anywhere in the application again after one of the two has been called.

Once you call `exit` you've basically said to the runtime "Hey I need to tear down the house" the house being your application. The runtime then runs `atexit` handlers per [the standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit).

Also worth noting is that `atexit` handlers are not guaranteed thread safe but `atexit` itself is, so if threads have registered their own `atexit` handlers those will get called.

So what does all this mean:

`exit` is not thread safe. But if you're tearing down the house does it really matter if the house was constructed to code anymore? Once you've called `exit` and the `atexit` handlers have finished then the kernel kills the threads, closes any handles, and reclaims everything. Worrying about closing the drapes when the bulldozer is coming through the wall is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) disallows `exit` from being called more than once.  Section 7.22.4.4 regarding the `exit` function paragraph 2 states:

> The `exit` function causes normal program termination to occur. No
> functions registered by  the `at_quick_exit` function  are  called.
> **If  a  program  calls  the `exit` function more than once, or calls the `quick_exit` function in addition to the `exit` function, the
> behavior is undefined.**

Additionally, the [POSIX man page for `exit`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3p.html), i.e. `man 3p exit` also states this:

> If  a  function registered by a call to atexit() fails to return, the
> remaining registered functions shall not be called and the rest of the
> exit()
> processing shall not be completed. **If exit() is called more than once, the behavior is undefined.**

So the function is not thread safe by definition.

Comment: C standard can never supersede POSIX because it is the standard that defines system's behavior and the one that refers to C standard and overrides parts of it.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Fair assessment.  Edited to reflect.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the answer is in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html
You call pthread_exit(). Not exit()
Eventually, when the last thread exits, exit is called for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the safety of using `exit()` directly.

Comment: But you're not supposed to call exit in a pthreads program for a graceful exit. exit is not part of the pthreads library directly.

Comment: If the function is thread-safe, as implied by not being in the list of unsafe functions, shouldn't it be OK to call it?

Comment: But if it isnt part of the pthreads set directly, are they required to list it ? Shouldnt the scope of what they talk about in the pthreads doc be limited to the pthreads set itself ? I'm open to learning, BTW.

Comment: Look at the list, they have nothing to do with threads. They're functions like `putenv()` and `rand()`.

Comment: You're right. They are listing things beyond just threads. Those things that they expect would be called from user code. I think they should have said something about exit too, even if they said dont call it. I have another thought. I'll put that in the comments on the question.

Answer (score -1):

`exit` is not thread-safe for these reasons:

- it abruptly terminates all the threads. How can something which kills all the threads be "thread-safe"?
- `exit` must not be called more than once; that is undefined behavior. Therefore the basic thread-safety question "can this function be called from two threads at around the same time" is not answerable in the affirmative.
- `exit` can execute arbitrary application code: the `atexit` handlers. According to POSIX, calling the `atexit` handlers is the first thing that `exit` does, and that means this happens while threads are running. These handlers can be badly written such that they lack thread safety, which means that their parent function, `exit`, is rendered unsafe.